# Visual Studios c++: Debug dll for 64 bit wont work

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging, dll

I'm trying to develop a plugin to an autodesk product, however it seems like i have a *interesting* problem... 
When i try to compile a 64bit debug dll. the software wont load it!
But when i use 64 Release dll, 32 Release and debug dll it works.

Feels like i'm missing some simple setting, but i compared all the value of the 32 and 64 bit debug config settings but they are the same (except those defining it as either 32 or 64).

Any suggestions what it could be?

I've tried using the example solutions they have aswell, same issues.
Also tried different versions of their software (motionbuilder 2011 and 2010).

Update: I now tried building a debug 64 dll from Maya 2011 example code, seem like it wont work either.

Comment: "Won't load"? Can you better describe the error?

Comment: The Software wont load the plugin

Comment: Is it possible you're missing a 3rd party dll specifically for the 64 debug?

Comment: I'm pretty sure i have everything i need since im trying out with their example code

Comment: Seems like the answer lied in the propertyi pages, c/c++ -> Code Generation -> changing Runtime library from /MDd to /MTd helped.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend you use `GetLastError` and `FormatMessage` if `LoadLibrary` returned `null`, also check the `EventViewer`.

I had a similar problem - `32 bit dll not loading in a 64bit environment` and it turned out to be side by side errors (failure to load VC debug dlls) and switching to a release build avoided that issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your variables are initialized correctly before used. I've seen many programs work on Debug build but crash on Release because I forgot to initialize something.

Comment: Even when i use their example code it still doesn't work, and i'm pretty sure they wont release example code that won't compile (even if it is autodesk).

Comment: Seems like the answer lied in the propertyi pages, c/c++ -> Code Generation -> changing Runtime library from /MDd to /MTd helped.

Answer (score 0):

Are you testing on a machine that doesn't have the Debug versions of the C Runtime Library, or any other dependent libraries?

If that doesn't help, enable [Loader Snaps](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/junfeng/archive/2006/11/20/debugging-loadlibrary-failures.aspx) and see what that tells you.